# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENDWHILE in /home/content/50/8454750/html/wp-content/themes/market/page.php on line 23

Tags: php, wordpress

here is my php code

```
<?php
get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area col-md-8">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>



            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

it shows an error that, 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENDWHILE in /home/content/50/8454750/html/wp-content/themes/market/page.php on line 23..
pls help me

```
thanks,
```

jini

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to add to add the while loop

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> // add this line
<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>
```

Remove this line -

```
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

</main><!-- #main -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

This will solve your problem.